# Change attributes of view on list item selection

Tags: android, listview, focus

I have a ListView which contains custom rows. This custom row has following UI elements

1. ImageView imageView1,imageView2
2. TextView textview1,textView2,textView3

The requirement is whenever the list row is SELECTED there would be following changes

imageView1 background,color is changed

imageView1 color is changed

textview1 color,size and typeface is changes

textview2 color,size is changed

textview3 color,size is changed

What would be the best way to design for this?

AFAIK we cannot apply styles in the selector. Is there a better way to work on this rather than handling in the java code?

We have setOnItemSelectedListener that can be set on a Listview which would have following callback methods:

i) onItemSelected

ii)  onNothingSelected

However there is no callback method which provide details of the item which has lost its focus. Is this a better place to make the changes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "AFAIK we cannot apply styles in the selector. Is there a better way to work on this rather than handling in the java code?" If you can't do it in a selector how else could it be done but in Java? Maybe you could override the the style attributes referred to by the default selector?

Comment: Styles can be applied to change the background color/drawable.It would not help to change the font size. Also do i need to specify the selector for each of the child views? In java code as in, inside getView().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do here is create a [Compound Control](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound). You can find an example in your  SDK directory in the samples//ApiDemos subdirectory (you may want to download the [Android source](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) if you don't have these directories).

What I would do is create a class that inherits from whatever kind of layout you are using for your custom row. Let's suppose it's a `LinearLayout` for this example. In your subclass constructor, you can inflate your layout from a resource, find the subViews and attach them to instance variables, and return the LinearLayout to the caller.

In this subclass, you can override `setSelected` and manipulate the subViews in whatever way you want.

Here's an example of what I am describing based on your post:

```
public class MyCustomLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public ImageView imageView1;   // These are public since you likely want
    public ImageView imageView2;   // to set them in your Adapter.
    public TextView textView1;
    public TextView textView2;
    public TextView textView3;

    public MyCustomLayout(Context ctxt) {
        super(ctxt);

        // The call below attaches the items in the mycustomlayout.xml file to this
        // instance, which serves as the root element in the layout.
        LayoutInflater.from(ctxt).inflate(R.layout.mycustomlayout, this, true);

        imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview3);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        super.setChecked(selected);
        if (selected) {
            imageView1.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000); // whatever color you want
            // Do all the rest of the setting of your subviews here for
            // the case when the row is selected.
        } else {
            imageView1.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000); // whatever color you want
            // Do all the rest of the setting of your subviews here for
            // the case when the row is not selected
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the mycustomlayout.xml file, you want to use the `<merge>` tag so that you don't create an unneeded layout:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview2" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3" />
</merge>
```

I've elided all the configuration of the subviews above, obviously, but you should get the idea about how to set up the XML file. You could also do this in code if you don't want to fool with XML and a LayoutInflater. You can look at [this helpful blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) on the Android dev blog which discusses a similar case towards the end.

Then, in your Adapter's `getView` you can just create (or recycle) instances of `MyCustomLayout`, set them up, and let the framework take care of keeping track of which rows are selected and which aren't selected.

Answer (score 0):

I have a crude way... but it is very process heavy... 
once an item is selected refresh your listview... only for the selected item it should show that particular font etc... and store the id of selected item in some variable to match it while populating the views in your adapter...

Answer (score 0):

Take One static integer variable `selectedPos` at Activity level.

in onItemSelected set that variable `selectedPos = position` and in onNothingSelected set it to `-1` and call notifyDataSetChanged() for your adapter object.

Now in ListView's Adapter Class.
write condition in getView as

```
if(position == selectedPos)
{
   // set color and background to view
}
```

and dont forget to write this two methods in adapter class,

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
 return _ArrayListObject.size();
}
```

Comment: Thanks soni. However this would mean to redraw the listView again for every item selected. Can this be avoided in any way ? Also notifyDataSetChanged() is supposed to be called when "underlying data has been changed" which is not the case here. Is there no support from framework to handle this case ?

Comment: @khotmanish nope.. :) :( .. I just have this idea in my mind and i think this will work for you..

Answer (score 0):

Khotmanish,

I'm not sure what you mean by the most efficient way. There are a number of ways that are very speedy, but it often depends on what you know ahead of time and what you do not. It must also be understood that dynamic view properties are heavily misunderstood, but highly efficient despite popular myths. The people at Google did an amazing job on the UI development.

If you know it ahead of time, you may simply create a StateListDrawable for each View and apply it to each as you run through your adapter.

To build your StateListDrawable, create one:

```
StateListDrawable _drawStates;
```

Then, for each state, add the drawable you need:

```
_drawStates.add(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, _newImage);
```

This is as simple as the following line in your getView() method for your adapter:

```
v.setBackgroundDrawable(_drawStates);
```

Alternatively, you may change the backgrounds dynamically according to the selection. This may be done in `OnListItemClick()`. You see, `OnListItemClick()` will give you the exact view that has been clicked. Once you have this, you may find the child by its `id` and change its properties and `invalidate()` it. I use this trick a lot. Saves me a lot of memory, but I'm not doing anything really processor intensive. You may change almost any property here without nearly any processing. Here is an example:

```
@Override protected void onListItemClick(final ListView inList, final View v, final int atPos, final long rowID)
{//Get the Child, set the properties
    ImageView _img = (ImageView)(v.findViewById(R.id.app_package));
    _img.setBackgroundColor(myClickedColor);
    _img.invalidate();  // <---- BEST Option
// ... OR ...
    v.invalidate();     // <---- 2nd Best Option
// ... OR ...
    inList.invalidate();  // <---- Last resort or specialized implementation
}
```

It is important to note that doing this dynamically has some caveats when it comes to background colors. You MUST get the child from the Clicked View... Not the ListView. Second, when changing background colors, you are in fact changing background Drawables. This means that all other "stateful" properties go away and you must change it back manually (if you wanted it to begin with).

Now, a more popular, but somewhat less flexible approach is to build your StateListDrawable in XML. There are a number of resources to learn how to do this on the Android Developer website.

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Thanks for your response Fuzzical Logic. However StateListDrawable would only change color/drawables. It won't be much of help for changing the font size. Also i am more interested in onSelect state rather than onClicked state. (I would be using the trackball instead of the onTouch). Hence onListItemClick won't help me with that :(. Anyway thanks for your brief answer :)